# Why does this trig equation have only 2 solutions and not 4?

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

Upon solving this equation:

$$
5\sin x - 5\cos x = 2
$$

for the interval $0 \le x < 360^\circ$, I manipulated it in order to get a solvable trigonometric equation below:

$$
\sin 2x = 21/25
$$

Normally this would procure 4 solutions: $28.6^\circ, 61.4^\circ, 208.6^\circ, 241.4^\circ$ (one can easily plot this into Desmos to see that it is true).

However, the answers only include the middle 2 solutions: $61.43^\circ, 208.57^\circ$. Why is this? Why do 2 of the solutions simply disappear? Could it have something to do with the way in which I manipulated the original equation (by squaring and substituting using the appropriate trigonometric identities)?

After looking at the original equation, it makes sense to some degree, but then I'm not a fan of such methods, especially since one could encounter more complicated equations in the future.

Am I missing/forgetting something fundamental?

Comment: How did you manipulate the original equation to get your $4$ answers ?

Comment: You do not need to use a double angle here. Recall that $\cos x=\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ and apply difference to product formula.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$$\sin{x}-\cos{x}=\frac{2}{5}$$
$$(\sin{x}-\cos{x})^2=\frac{4}{25}$$
$$1-2\sin{x}\cos{x}=\frac{4}{25}$$
$$\sin{2x}=\frac{21}{25}$$

In the second step, when we square both sides, we inadvertently include the solutions of:
$$\sin{x}-\cos{x}=-\frac{2}{5}$$
This equation is true for $28.6^{\circ}$ and $241.4^{\circ}$, which are the extra two solutions which we don't need.

Comment: Thanks, this makes total sense. That was the exact mistake I made, by squaring both sides, and forgot that this would invoke the existence of the other 2 solutions. 

Appreciate the help!